# Visualization of residues in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

When we have a meromorphic function we can visualise its singularities as places where the graph of the function blows up.

Like on this picture of the gamma function:

[image]

My question is:

is there any way we can visualise residues of a complex function geometrically ?

Or is the only way we can think of it as:
$$\operatorname{Res}(f, z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C} f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z$$

and

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n (z-z_0)^n = \cdots + \frac{c_{-2}}{(z-z_0)^2} + \frac{c_{-1}}{z-z_0} + c_0 + c_1(z-z_0) + c_2(z-z_0)^2 + \cdots$$

where the residue is

$$\operatorname{Res}(f, z_0) = c_{-1}.$$

Comment: If you can visualize the difference between, say, $1/z$ and $2/z$, then you can visualize the difference between residue one and residue two.

Answer (score 1):

Felix Klein wrote an extended essay

*On Riemann's Theory of Algebraic Functions and their Integrals*

in which he attempted to present some visual depictions of the singularities of rational functions on the extended complex plane. Basically he was depicting velocity flow-field patterns and electric fields.
However, these pictures do not  convey detailed numerical information about the values of the residues. Tristan Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis* is written in a similar spirit.

One subtlety is that e.g at a double pole such as $f(z)= 3z^{-2}+ 6 z^{-1} + \ldots$ the dominant singularity $z^{-2}$ contributes nothing to the residue, which instead is the coefficient $6$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I have read Needham's Visual Complex Analysis and it was very enjoyable. He indeed does visualise singularities and other topics, but regarding the residues, the geometrical representation is nowhere to be found. I thought that residues could actually be seen on the function's graph when the real and imaginary part of the complex function each are plotted in $\mathbb{R^3}$, but maybe the residues aren't particularly "geometrical" and it is silly to think about them in that way.